# Unix: What is the timing resolution of ls -t?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ls

I'm using `ls -t` to process my files by timing order where `ls -t` refers to the modification time.

My question is : how precise is this `-t` option? Seconds, milliseconds or nanoseconds?

Comment: It's a good question, but system-dependent. It depends on the OS, filesystem, `ls` flavour.

Comment: For the record: I voted to move this question to Unix & Linux, which is what I think that should be done. It is a good question and fits better there: migration is the solution, not just closing.

Comment: `ls` just reports the time saved in the file metadata by the file system. It doesn't have a resolution of its own.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the operating system and the file system used, so there is no definitive answer to this question without specifying a precise environment.

For example, FAT12/16/32 has a creation timestamp resolution of 10ms but the modification timestamp resolution is only 2s. So even if the OS supports a higher timer resolution (pretty likely ;-) you will not get timestamps that are more precise than this 2s resolution.

On the other hand, if you have a filesystem with 1 nanosecond timestamp resolution (like ext4, btrfs, XFS or ZFS) but your OS kernel's timer only has a 1 millisecond resolution this is again the limiting factor and you won't get more precise than 1 millisecond.

For a list of some filesystem resolutions, see the [Wikipedia article "Comparison of file systems"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems). It's not complete and only lists the *maximum* resolution which might be misleading as can be seen with FAT12/16/32 which have different resolutions for creation (10ms) and modification (2s) timestamps.

Comment: In other words, what file system and OS? ex: Solaris 10, ZFS or maybe Red Hat Linux and ext4.

Comment: @jimmcnamara: You might need to be more precise and need to specify the kernel version. Most of the time, the FS is limiting factor (for example, FAT12-32 has a resolution of 10ms, ext2/3 just 1s, but ext4 1ns). But even if the FS has a high precision it might be "spoiled" if the OS's timer resolution is lower.

Comment: Oh, FAT12-32's modification time has a 2s resolution only…

Comment: The linked Wikipedia article has no mention of timestamp resolution that I can find. Looks like it was removed in July 2015.